# random Soap Error: Couldn't load from

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

While consuming the webservice, I sometimes get this error. And they are pretty sure their webservice is up and running.

Our server is amazon ec2 and php version is : PHP 5.3.20

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from `'http://...webservice..asmx?wsdl'` : failed to load external entity "`http://...webservice..asmx?wsdl`"

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try  enabling the php_openssl extension in your local server by only uncommening  the line "extension=php_openssl.dll" in you  php.ini file

Comment: what if there is no such line ?

Comment: probably you have to install it because you need it in order to access the wsdl url

Comment: I installed it, but still having that error randomly. I can access properly %98 time but other times giving me this error on logs..